# Share data between third party applications

Tags: ios, objective-c

stupid question again., yes there are lot of questions on same topic.But i'm confused a lot with 
1.urlschemes
2.uidocumentation controller

some of them said, it's possible to exchange data between two apps using url schemes and ui documentation controller.

some of them said it's not possible because iphone app's are sandboxed.

My question, by using url schemes we can open B app from A app if we know urlscheme address of B app. and is it possible to access their files,? if so what are the permissions for following parameters

```
1.Read-yes/no
2.write-yes/no
3.modify-yes/no
4.copy-yes/no.
```

i'm confused because some blogs are saying that we can read files but not allowed to modify and write.
Actually i'm trying to use files from other app, i trying to copy file from thier documents, can someone give me straight answer, is it possible or not. even if it's possible does apple allows that?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible to access another app's files. URL schemes and `UIDocumentInteractionController` will allow you to send data to another app, but will not give you a way to read or modify files that belong to another app. iOS 8 will change this with a storage provider, but this will only be available in iOS 8 and later.

Comment: thanks for reply. so what's main purpose of urlschemes @strwils is it for calling ios standard apps only?

Comment: You can use URL schemes to call any app that is configured to receive them; however if the app is not installed on the user's device it will be ineffective.

Comment: URL schemes are for sending data. If you want to use another app's functionality, you open the app and pass data to it using its URL scheme. The other app is not able to access your app's files though. It only has access to the data that is part of the URL passed to it.